# Opening bootstrap select in bootstrap table issue

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-table, bootstrap-select

#### The Problem

I am using the [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn) plugin and the [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) plugin, which both work very nice.
But I get an issue when I use the bootstrap-select *inside* a bootstrap-table.
If the select box of the last row opens, the table size changes instead of the selectbox going "over" the table area creating a scroll area which I do not like.

Like in the image below:
[image]

I have tried to "fix" this effect using the below javascript code, but to no avail. The code gets executed but the problem is still there. I do not see which css is responsible for this behaviour and any help is highly appreciated.

```
$('.table-responsive').on('show.bs.select', function () { 
  console.log("triggered show bs select");
  $('.table-responsive').css( "overflow", "hidden" ); 
}); 
$('.table-responsive').on('hide.bs.select', function () { 
  console.log("triggered hide bs select");
  $('.table-responsive').css( "overflow", "auto" ); 
})
```

#### Example

The behaviour can be seen in:
**Jsfiddle:**http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/8612/

---

### Edit

I have it working now but only with applying padding-bottom on the table and using the following js code:

```
$('.table-responsive').on('show.bs.select', function () { 
      $('.table-responsive').css( "overflow", "inherit" );
      $('.bootstrap-table').css( "overflow", "inherit" ); 
      $('.fixed-table-body').css( "overflow", "inherit" );     
 });
```

I leave the question open for now since this is not a "nice" fix in my oppinion, especially the added padding which is needed to "hide" the select box again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add the option `container: 'body'`. This will place the drop-down outside the table and will prevent the issue. If there's a problem with `body`, just use any element that contains the table, which is large enough to contain the drop-down menu.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1eqrgopz/)

Comment: use  it like 
<select data-container="body" ..... other options> 
</select>

Comment: That is real answer

Answer (score 2):

The class `.fixed-table-body` seems to be causing this. Removing `overflow-x: auto;` and `overflow-x: auto;` fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed those but a bit more in my case was needed to make it work completely. If no better / nicer solution shows up I will accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The class .table-responsive seems to be causing this. Removing overflow-x: auto;  fixes your issue. You can find the style in bootstrap.css

Comment: Comments should not be in answer section