# Drop scroll using select in last line of the table

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, overflow

I made a custom dropdown. In the last line of the table, scroll is created when dropdown is open. I need to scroll to see dropdown elements. I do not want this.

I want you to open up the body of the dropdown or enlarge the body. How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Share some code. It is impossible to tell what should be done.

Comment: I did not share code because I did not know what the problem was.t he problem is the same. but I use react and I created a custom dropdown.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39570611/opening-bootstrap-select-in-bootstrap-table-issue

Answer (score 0):

Document is already enlarged by enlarged content/element, scroll shows that. You need only scroll to view entire enlarged element, f.e.:

```
elmnt.scrollIntoView(false);
```

Real problem (using react) is that **should be done after change state and rendering** enlarged element.

I probably would use `setTimeout` called from `setState` callback. It's quite common way to be sure it's called after updating state/view. You'll find examples on SO.